# Не понимаю какую пременную вставить в цикл for, не млгу составить формулы

Tags: c++, циклы, формулы

Задача:
Представьте, что вы собираетесь пригласить к себе шестерых гостей, но за вашим столом могут разместиться всего лишь 4 человека. Сколькими способами можно разместить четырех из шести гостей за обеденным столом? Каждый из шести гостей может разместиться на первом стуле. Каждый из оставшихся пяти гостей может занять второй стул. На третьем стуле может разместиться один из четырех гостей, и на четвертом - один из трех оставшихся гостей. Двоим из гостей не достанется ни одного места. Таким образом, число возможных рассадок гостей за столом равно 6*5*4*3=360. Напишите программу, которая будет производить аналогичные вычисления для любого числа гостей и любого числа мест за столом (при этом предполагается, что число гостей не меньше числа мест). Программа не должна быть сложной, и вычисление можно организовать с помощью простого цикла for.

Подскажите как составить формулу и использовать цикл в данном случае

Answer (score 0):

N гостей, M мест - если порядок мест важен - то это число *размещений* N по M, и равно N!/(N-M)!

Считать - проще пареной репы (если не рассматривать большие числа, которые не помещаются в `int`):

```
int count = 1;
for(int i = N; i > N-M; --i) count *= i;
```